# How much are bitcoins worth?

Tags: exchange-rate

I'm new to this bitcoin thing-I am trying to find out what is the conversion of bitcoins to US money? I.E. a bitcoin is equal to how much US dollars? Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+value+usd

Comment: While this question is very poorly worded, changing it to something like "where can I see actual bitcoin value" would be enough to save it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow Lohoris-sorry my question was *Poorly worded*... kinda harsh to pick at me for something so small isn't it? I mean you did understand what I was asking right? I don't claim to be a genius-just trying to get answers... thank you all for answering. So if something was B1.34 how much would that be please?

Comment: @user3007 I was trying to help you salvage it, since other people want to close this instead...

Answer (score 4):

The best place to find bitcoin's current value is probably [bitcoincharts](http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD#rg60ztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv).

Answer (score 1):

The largest bitcoin exchange is MtGox: the MtGox "last" value is usually what people refer to when they say "a bitcoin is worth x US Dollars".  Go to https://mtgox.com/ and look at the very top of the page for this value along with a few other trading statistics.

You can buy/sell bitcoins at different rates via other exchanges, but you'll probably get the best deal on MtGox.  One potential downside is that MtGox requires you to verify your account in order to trade- this requires a government-issued ID and proof of address such as a utility bill.  Other sites will sell/buy bitcoins to/from you without this information but may charge you more/give you less than you could trade for at MtGox.